# Calling EWS services through Managed API by using Oauth (ADAL azure active directory library) 401 Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint, azure, oauth, ews-managed-api

I am developing a Provider hosted app in sharepoint for calling EWS services. I am using managed api.

below is my code,

```
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential("********-****-****-****-********e042", "b/2i******n07QKJ********0uhVVvv*****BUs=");
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/");
AuthenticationResult result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken("https://outlook.office365.com/", cc);
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(result.AccessToken);

service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
CalendarView calView = new CalendarView(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddHours(24));

Mailbox m = new Mailbox("xxxx@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com");

FolderId CalendarFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, m);

FindItemsResults<Appointment> master = service.FindAppointments(CalendarFolderId, calView);
```

The error that i am getting is 401 unauthorized..
following is the stack trace,

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned
>   an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>
> Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6540964
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +29
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request) +34

[ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request) +149
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request) +407
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute() +36
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(IEnumerable`1 parentFolderIds, SearchFilter searchFilter, String queryString, ViewBase view, Grouping groupBy, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandlingMode) +263
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindAppointments(FolderId parentFolderId, CalendarView calendarView) +62
   SharePointApp2Web.Pages.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1004
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Any thoughts on this will be helpful.

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've edited your question to make it a bit easier to read. 4 indents will make code look good :)